# Clarification of close reason -- norepro / typo

Tags: support, close-reasons

One of our custom close reasons is:

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

With this in mind, I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29983964/c-sharp-number-adding-program) as off-topic -- since it is caused by an obvious issue of a `=` in place of a `+`.

But since that, the question has six answers and the flag was disputed. Some even with up-votes.

In what situations should this close reason be used? And how can I tell whether it applies to a question?

Comment: It has been closed now, gifted it a close vote.

Comment: Should not have happened.  Keep in mind that SO goes a little nutso twice a year, coinciding with students finishing their end-of-semester assignments.  The influx is particularly heavy this month.  Best to suspend the expectation of normalcy for another fat 4 weeks.

Comment: @HansPassant Ah, yes... the [eternal September](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/S/September-that-never-ended.html).

Comment: I haven't found a Close Votes review for that question, but only a Triage review with [unanimous *Looks Ok*](http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7904748). I don't know whether your flag was before or after the review, but if the reviewers didn't read the question carefully, it's not possible to see this. The problem is probably, that it was not clear enough from the comments that this was a typo early on or even now. Although it's deleted now. If you're going to flag this. Add a comment saying where typo is and also call this a "typo question".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When the answer to the question boils down to something simple that you either did not key or keyed one character incorrectly, it is a simple typographical error. In this case, the user probably missed the shift key when trying to type their "+" in their code, causing their error.

In rare cases, a "typo" question can actually be useful. If the typo is an error that might be a little more difficult to spot, then it may be useful to future readers. In these cases, the question should be left open. However, in most cases, the typo question is not useful to other users and should just be closed.

When the error in the question has been run and no other users can hit the same error, be it because the error is in a different section of code or an update fixed the error, it is not reproducible. These questions should be closed as they will not help future readers, especially if it's a case of the error is not in that section of code. Usually, these questions are unanswerable or only answerable with "This was resolved in the latest update of X."

With "typo" questions, you usually have to find the answer before you realize it should be closed as a "typo" question. If the typo is obvious, this won't take very long. If it's not, it might take a few minutes of reading the code to process what's wrong or missing where. In the case of "not reproducible" questions, it usually won't be apparent until a user attempts to run the code in question.

Answer (score 11):

In this case, the original questioner commented on one of the answers:

> I must have read over that typo. Thank you!

I don't see how you could have a clearer case of "a simple typographical error". He knew what he wanted to write, he just missed the shift key, and as soon as someone pointed it out to him, he saw the problem. As the wording for the close reason says:

> … this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

This question isn't going to be useful to anyone else, nor are the 5 duplicate repwhoring answers.

[Johan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29984018/908494) explains the difference between `=` and `+` in C#, and that might be useful to someone… but no such person is going to find it through this question. So, it's a shame that he wasted that good effort, but what are you going to do?

So, I think you did exactly the right thing.